# Datatable refresh after change field and no ajax

Tags: jquery, datatable, datatables

What I'm trying to do is sort a datatable column which has a checkbox. The question is: it is not working because I'm changing the column value.
As it is not ajax generated and I cant use reload() method, how redraw it?

[jsFiddle code](https://jsfiddle.net/35znhucL/1/)

```
<table id="tableEditable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>Column 1</td>
      <td>Column 2</td>
      <td>Column 3</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Info 1</td>
      <td>Info 2</td>
      <td><span id="spanChk1">0</span><input type="checkbox" id="chk1" onclick="changeValue('spanChk1', this.checked)"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Info 3</td>
      <td>Info 4</td>
      <td><span id="spanChk2">0</span><input type="checkbox" id="chk2" onclick="changeValue('spanChk2', this.checked)"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#tableEditable').DataTable({
    "columnDefs": [
      {
        "targets": 2,
        "orderDataType": "dom-checkbox"
      }
    ],
    "paging": false,
    "order": [[1, "asc"]]
  });
});

function changeValue(spanId, checked)
{
    if (!checked)
    $("#" + spanId).text('0');
  else
    $("#" + spanId).text('1');
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following approach to sort a column containing checkboxes.

The behavior will be as follows:

1. When the checkbox column is not sorted, clicking on a checkbox will simply check and uncheck it.
2. When the checkbox column is sorted, all checked rows will be sorted to the top of the table (when "ascending" is applied), or to the bottom (for "descending").
3. When a checkbox is clicked while that column has sorting applied, that row will immediately move, if necessary, to ensure the sort order is preserved.

Here is the code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $.fn.dataTable.ext.type.order['check-sort-pre'] = function ( data ) {
    return data.includes('checked=""') ? 0 : 1;
  };

  var table = $('#tableEditable').DataTable( {
    columnDefs: [ {
      type: "check-sort",
      targets: 2
    } ]
  } );

  $( "#tableEditable" ).on( "click", "input:checkbox", function() {
    var cell = table.cell( $(this).parent() );
    var checkHtml = cell.data();
    if (checkHtml.includes('checked=""')) {
        checkHtml = checkHtml.replace('checked=""', '');
    } else {
      index = checkHtml.length -1;
      checkHtml = checkHtml.slice(0, index) + ' checked=""' + checkHtml.slice(index);
    }
    cell.data(checkHtml);
    table.draw( true );
  });

} );
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Demo</title>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.22/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.22/css/jquery.dataTables.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://datatables.net/media/css/site-examples.css">

</head>

<body>

<div style="margin: 20px;">

<table id="tableEditable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>Column 1</td>
      <td>Column 2</td>
      <td>Column 3</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Info 1</td>
      <td>Info 2</td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" id="chk1"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Info 3</td>
      <td>Info 4</td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" id="chk2"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Info 5</td>
      <td>Info 6</td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" id="chk3"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Info 7</td>
      <td>Info 8</td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" id="chk4" checked></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Info 9</td>
      <td>Info 10</td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" id="chk5"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

There are two different techniques used here:

1. A custom data type is defined (`type: "check-sort"`) and then that type is used by the `$.fn.dataTable.ext.type.order['check-sort-pre']` function. The function detects if the checkbox is checked or not. It returns `0` if the checkbox is checked, and `1` otherwise. Since `0` is lower than `1`, then checked rows are sorted before unchecked rows (assuming an ascending sort).
2. A delegated event handler is declared, to capture checkbox clicks. If the checkbox is already checked, then the HTML for the checkbox is adjusted to remove the `checked` attribute (otherwise the attribute is added). The updated HTML is then used to update the DataTable cell - cell.data(checkHtml) - and finally the table is re-drawn: `table.draw( true )`.

The only word of caution here: It may be disconcerting for your users, when they see rows move (or maybe even apparently disappear, if they are sorted to a different page) when they are checked/unchecked, due to the applied sort order.

Comment: thank ur attention but it didnt work. I tried this way and worked: https://jsfiddle.net/ex84vnf3/1/

Comment: Your approach only works if you force every row to be on one page by using `"paging": false`. My approach does not have that limitation.

Comment: but I tried ur suggestion and it didnt work :C

Comment: If you click on the blue "Run Code Snippet" button above, can you describe what isn't working? What behavior are you seeing, which is not what you expect?

Comment: sorry my delay. idk why ur example didnt work on jsfiddle but "run code snippet" yes. btw as I m not using paging, its solved. ty again